# Select all files with extension

Tags: windows

I am trying to select all files with extension "cs" but I do not want the ones with ".generated.cs" ... How can I do this? I tried the following:

```
*.cs
```

But this also selects all files with .generated.cs

Comment: How are you selecting these files?

Comment: I am using this in a library that requires me to define a whitelist and they use *.cs ... but I would like to deny *.generated.cs ... But I am not sure of how they do it internally

Answer (score 0):

Combining several methods into one, this should work. If it doesn't just drop me a comment.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(yourDirectory,"*.cs").Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".generated.cs"));
```

Comment: I need to include this in a string ... Is it possible? I do not have access to the C# code.

Comment: You're trying to include this in a string? What is the interface between your code and the library?

Comment: Just a String. Instead of using *.cs I would like to tell *.cs and not *.generared.cs ... I am not sure if this is possible. Is it?

Comment: What is the library? I can take a look at the function if you like? But as a string I don't believe there's a way of limiting the wildcard.